# How to sum over $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{(0,0)\}$?

Tags: functions, summation

I want to sum over $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{ Z} \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ . So, something like

```
Sum[f[m,n],{m,-Infinity,Infinity},{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

but I want to exclude f[0,0] as infinities might appear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If `f[0,0]` is defined, then `Sum[f[m,n],{m,-Infinity,Infinity},{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]-f[0,0]`. If not, then try `Sum[f[m,n]*(1-KroneckerDelta[m,,n],{m,-Infinity,Infinity},{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]`.

Comment: Sadly it is not defined.

Comment: Can you remove the singularity (by adding $+i\eta$ in the denominator, for example)? Then, after analytic summing over the entire $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, subtract $f(0,0)$ and then take the limit $\eta\to0^+$.

Comment: Thanks, will try this;

Comment: @Roman: The same results are produced by your approach and mine for `f[n_,k_]:=1/(n+I*k)^2`, but my code seems faster.

Comment: Just split the sum into 4 sums in each of the quadrants.

Comment: @yarchik: How about the axes? –

Comment: @user64494 Right, axes must be treated properly too. :)  It is a pity that OP does not provide any example.

Comment: If you're summing nontrivial sums (not absolutely convergent, as @Somos points out), then the mathematicians have an arsenal of tools available: starting with [Poisson summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) and extending to generalized ζ-functions. [This solution on Euclidean ζ-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1954135/632893) could be a good start on how to use Fourier transforms of sums over the integers $\mathbb{Z}^n\setminus0$.
Maybe the [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) will be a good place to ask for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a function

```
sumZZ0[f_, M_:Infinity] := (
      Sum[f[n, k], {n, M}, {k, 0, M}]
    + Sum[f[k, -n], {n, M}, {k, 0, M}]
    + Sum[f[-n, -k], {n, M}, {k, 0, M}]
    + Sum[f[-k, n], {n, M}, {k, 0, M}]);
```

This code may or may not help you depending on which `f[n,k]` you want to sum.
If the original sum is not absolutely convergent, then splitting
the sum into four sums may not give correct results.

As a simple example, using `sumZZ0[(#1 + #2 I)^-4 &]` to evaluate the
[Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) $G_4(i)$
does not produce a useful result. However, the code

```
Sum[Piecewise[{{(n + k I)^-4, n^2 + k^2 != 0}, {0, True}}],
   {n, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

does produce a useful result after a few seconds.

Still, an example that works is `sumZZ0[x^(#1^2 + #2^2) &]`
which returns `-1 + EllipticTheta[3, 0, x]^2` as it should
in under a second. The code

```
 Sum[If[n == 0 && k == 0, 0, x^(n^2 + k^2)],
    {n, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

takes much longer to produce the same result. Also, using
the `Piecewise` method takes even longer.

Comment: `Sum[Piecewise[{{x^(m^2 + n^2), m^2 + n^2 != 0}, {0, 
    True}}], {m, -Infinity, Infinity}, {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]` also returns `-1 + EllipticTheta[3, 0, x]^2`., though slowly. This example is shooting a cannon at sparrows.

Comment: I'd like to add that `-1 + EllipticTheta[3, 0, x]^2` is a formal result since the series under consideration diverges if `Abs[x]>1`.

Comment: In fact, this is my approach, onlly expressed by a complicated and uncommented code. I don't see any advantage.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of dealing with indices, try

```
Sum[Piecewise[{{f[m, n], m^2 + n^2 != 0}, {0, True}}], {m, -Infinity,  Infinity}, {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

It should be noticed the notation `n,k` is preferable over `n,m` which are similar.

Comment: Yes, it works in general. But, sadly not in my case... Other problems.

Comment: @niloderoock: Please, present your case. What was asked, that was answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
Sum[If[n == 0 && m == 0,0, f[m,n]],{m,-Infinity,Infinity},{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

Comment: This is my approach only formulated in other formulas. I don't see any advantage.